# An interesting extension of a combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinations, binomial-theorem

Yesterday , i saw a question on this site.. I don't know where it went now..
It was as follows

Q. Find the number of ways of going from (0,0) to (m,n) given that one step can be :-

m,n>0

- either 1 unit up
- or 1 unit right
- or √2 unit up-right along the diagonal

I made cases as follows :-

- paths having only 1 diagonal step
- paths having 2 diagonal steps..
- paths having 3 diagonal steps and so on..
  I summed all of them 
  and got the answer as :-

$$\sum_{r=0}^{n} {m+n-r \choose n} {n \choose r}$$

But  am unable to calculate this.. When i tried , The fact that the no. Of things to choose from was varying was of particular trouble. Two such problems(with variable things to choose from) i had done before involved the use of reduction formula of binomial coefficients.. But here i couldn't apply it.

Please help.. I would be grateful.

I am just a high school student.

Comment: You are asking about the [Delannoy numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delannoy_number).